# Adding swipe support to multiple classes

Tags: object-oriented, swift, ios, event-handling, user-interface

I have implemented swipe functionality using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in a project.

What I have done is added `PanGesture` to `UIView`:

```
self.panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panThisCell))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

And its selector is as:

```
func panThisCell(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    if recognizer != panGesture{  return }

    let point = recognizer.locationInView(self.collectionView)
    let indexpath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point)
    if indexpath == nil{  return }
    guard let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexpath!) as? TileCollectionViewCell else{

        return

    }
    .......
}
```

And helper methods that animates to show/hide background view are as follows which takes cell of class `TileCollectionViewCell` so that I don't have to typecast it later:

```
func resetConstraintToZero(cell:TileCollectionViewCell, animate:Bool,notifyDelegateDidClose:Bool){

        if (cell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant == 0 &&
            cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant == 0) {
            //Already all the way closed, no bounce necessary
            return;
        }
        cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = -kBounceValue;
        cell.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant = kBounceValue;
        self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded(cell,animated: animate) {
            cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = 0;
            cell.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant = 0;

            self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded(cell,animated: animate, completionHandler: {

                cell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant = cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant;
            })
        }
        cell.startPoint = CGPoint()
    }

    func setConstraintsToShowAllButtons(cell:TileCollectionViewCell, animate:Bool,notifyDelegateDidOpen:Bool){

        if (cell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant == self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell) &&
            cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant == self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell)) {
            return;
        }
        cell.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant = -self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell) - kBounceValue;
        cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell) + kBounceValue;

        self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded(cell,animated: animate) {
            cell.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant =  -(self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell))
            cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = self.getButtonTotalWidth(cell)

            self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded(cell,animated: animate, completionHandler: {(check) in

                cell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant = cell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant;
            })
        }
    }
```

I am thinking of implementing same swipe functionality on to another `UICollectionView` which is in the same `ViewController`, so I would like to reuse those methods. Custom cells are the exact same.

```
class TileCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var swipeView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var customTextLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var customContentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentViewLeftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentViewRightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!


    var startPoint = CGPoint()
    var startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant = CGFloat()


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}


class SecondTileCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var swipeView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var customTextLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var customContentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentViewLeftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentViewRightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!


    var startPoint = CGPoint()
    var startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant = CGFloat()


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

}
```

I am thinking of making those helper methods accept `AnyObject` instead of `TileCollectionViewCell` and later downcast to the appropriate type and perform operations. However, this requires an `if let` which makes the code more messy.

```
func resetConstraintToZero(cell:AnyObject, animate:Bool,notifyDelegateDidClose:Bool){

        if let firstCell = cell as? TileCollectionViewCell {


            if (firstCell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant == 0 &&
                firstCell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant == 0) {
                //Already all the way closed, no bounce necessary
                return;
            }
            firstCell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = -kBounceValue;
            firstCell.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant = kBounceValue;
            self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded(firstCell,animated: animate) {
                firstCell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = 0;
                firstCell.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant = 0;

                self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded(firstCell,animated: animate, completionHandler: {

                    firstCell.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant = firstCell.contentViewRightConstraint.constant;
                })
            }
            firstCell.startPoint = CGPoint()

        }else  {

            let secondCel = cell as! SecondTileCollectionViewCell

            if (secondCel.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant == 0 &&
                secondCel.contentViewRightConstraint.constant == 0) {
                //Already all the way closed, no bounce necessary
                return;
            }
            secondCel.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = -kBounceValue;
            secondCel.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant = kBounceValue;
            self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded(secondCel,animated: animate) {
                secondCel.contentViewRightConstraint.constant = 0;
                secondCel.contentViewLeftConstraint.constant = 0;

                self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded(secondCel,animated: animate, completionHandler: {

                    secondCel.startingRightLayoutConstraintConstant = chartCel.contentViewRightConstraint.constant;
                })
            }
            secondCel.startPoint = CGPoint()
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the `if else` has the same job but only the class is varying. What kind of pattern should I use to deal with this case?

Here is the [project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-QXZW4M8ozMR2FRUUlyQmJCejQ)

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by your last question?  Does this have to do with something not yet implemented (some particular case)?

Comment: @Jamal Actually i can implement the same functionality repeating the code for another collection View..But i mean is there a way i can use the same code of helper methods for both collection view.

Comment: I'll post this question [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) since I can't quite tell if it fits best here.  Regardless, I'd recommend not starting a bounty so soon since cancellations are not guaranteed.

Comment: @Jamal i started a bounty..i will see if there is a way  i can cancel the bounty

Comment: Only a mod can do that, which is why I first need to determine whether or not this question is off-topic.

Comment: @Jamal It sounds like he want to make the code do the same thing in a better way so this sounds on-topic to me.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Yes, i want to make the single code do the same thing for both class. Sometime i think i am in illusion trying to make a class manipulate properties of different classes having same name and data type.

Comment: Since the code appears to be on-topic, then there'd be no reason to cancel the bounty.  Such cancellation is done rarely anyway.

Comment: Create a protocol that declares all shared functionality, then implement that protocol in your two types

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Actually i am trying to create a generic method on controller..Because i have added pan gesture to collection View not at cell